# How to change ndots option default value of dns in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I want to change ndots default value from 5 to 3 in all pods in Kubernetes.
for example, this is the current resolv.conf output from one of my pods. How can I change the value of ndots from 5 to 3 in all current and future pods:

```
[root@master01 ~]# kubectl exec test-7c9b9bc678-kfcsj -- cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

Kubernetes version: 1.18.
Install on bare metal servers.
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: Kubernetes version 1.18. Install on bare metal servers

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust this configuration in the pod's `dnsConfig` section. See more details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-dns-config).

We are doing the same in the helm chart responsible for deploying applications into our cluster, like so -

```
dnsConfig:
  options:
    - name: ndots
      value: "3"
```

Comment: Thanks but this config is in pod resource and I don't want to add this part in all YAML files.  I want to change one config (coredns or kubelet) and then every pod that will create in the future will be ndots:3 in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: I don't think this can be changed by coredns or kubelet configuration. If you'd like to make the change in a single point you can add a mutation webhook to your cluster, which will add this dnsConfig to each new pod scheduled.

Comment: Seems like someone already created such a webhook: https://github.com/karampok/dnsconfig-injector

Comment: For the sake of my sanity can someone tell me why on earth this "ndots: 5" is the default?  From what I can tell, it breaks literally all name resolution, always (at least seems so in alpine containers as virtually all my pods are based on that).  The only way I ever can get dns resolution to work from these containers is by suffixing the hostname with a "." to make it explicit is it an FQDN.

Comment: Because with all of the shifting left, they forgot to invite sysadmins to the design meetings.  ndots:5 as a default is operational malpractice, and deserving of divine retribution.

Comment: @mritalian Speculation here, but I think it's because distros like Alpine use musl instead of glibc.

From https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html#Name_Resolver_.2F_DNS

> those with at least as many dots as ndots are only tried in the global namespace (never falling back to search...

So if you have ndots set to 1 like the glibc default, and you did a search for "myhost.mysubdomain" it wouldn't append the search domain "mydomain.com".  It was probably deemed worth it to set ndots to a higher value to reduce the chance of lookup errors for short domain names.